# Javascript Window.Open Opens the Target URL in Both a New Window and the Same

Tags: javascript, wordpress, window.open

Basically, I have a page with social media share buttons. Some of them work as they should (they open up in a new window), however, others open up both in a new window and in the same window. I have been going crazy for a day now over this and I cannot seem to find a way to fix it.

For reference, this is the page: http://www.inetsolutions.org/gsa-search-engine-ranker-ultimate-tutorial-and-genuine-review-seo-software-of-the-gods/

Link that works as expected (Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ism_link" onclick="indeedPinterestPopUp(2513);ism_fake_increment('.pinterest_share_count', 'pinterest', 'http://www.inetsolutions.org/gsa-search-engine-ranker-ultimate-tutorial-and-genuine-review-seo-software-of-the-gods/');">
```

Link that opens the URL to share in both a new window and in the same:

```
<a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/badge/?url=http://www.inetsolutions.org/gsa-search-engine-ranker-ultimate-tutorial-and-genuine-review-seo-software-of-the-gods/&amp;title=GSA%20Search%20Engine%20Ranker%20Ultimate%20Tutorial%20and%20Genuine%20Review%20%E2%80%93%20SEO%20Software%20of%20the%20Gods" class="ism_link" onclick="ism_fake_increment('.stumbleupon_share_count', 'stumbleupon', 'http://www.inetsolutions.org/gsa-search-engine-ranker-ultimate-tutorial-and-genuine-review-seo-software-of-the-gods/');return !window.open(this.href, '', 'width=700,height=575');">
```

What I have tried:

- I have tried to remove the "href" attribute of the  tag and insert the URL string into the window.open function instead of using "this.href". When I do that, the link opens only a new window, but doesn't open the share page of the respective social media, but rather, the target URL.
- I have tried to add "return false" after the non-working window.open function.
- I have also tried to remove the "ism_fake_increment" function just to test, but again, to no avail.
- I have contacted the plugin author, but they requested to access my website internally, which is not going to happen.

Any ideas will be strongly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: In the second link, try putting `event.preventDefault()` in the beginning of the `onclick` attribute. I'm not sure if it will work, though, and in general, using the `onclick` attribute is just a bad idea. Use `.addEventListener()` for better JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise that you don't use the `onclick` attribute because it leads to extremely messy code. Instead, use the `.addEventListener()` in the DOM.

To disable the link from opening the link in the same window, just disable the default even. This can be done with `.addEventListener()` in the callback by calling the `.preventDefault()` method of the object passed into the callback:

```js
//Get our link:
var link = document.getElementById("stumbleupon");
//Bind the click event:
link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    //Prevent the link from opening regularly with .preventDefault():
    event.preventDefault();
    //The following code with the plugin does not work because we haven't included the plugin in the code snippet, but as you can clearly see if you click the link, the link has clearly been disabled because of the above call to .preventDefault().
     
    //Do different stuff with the plugin:
    ism_fake_increment('.stumbleupon_share_count', 'stumbleupon', 'http://www.inetsolutions.org/gsa-search-engine-ranker-ultimate-tutorial-and-genuine-review-seo-software-of-the-gods/');
    return !window.open(this.href, '', 'width=700,height=575');
});
```

```html
<!-- Set the ID attribute so we can find this link in the DOM: -->
<a id="stumbleupon" href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/badge/?url=http://www.inetsolutions.org/gsa-search-engine-ranker-ultimate-tutorial-and-genuine-review-seo-software-of-the-gods/&amp;title=GSA%20Search%20Engine%20Ranker%20Ultimate%20Tutorial%20and%20Genuine%20Review%20%E2%80%93%20SEO%20Software%20of%20the%20Gods" class="ism_link">Hello! This is a link to stumbleupon.com!</a>
```